# nullpointer when setting adapter

Tags: java, android, listview

I am trying to set an adapter for a `ListView` in one of my fragments. However, I am receiving a null pointer error and I'm not sure whats wrong.

```
public class OptionsFragment extends Fragment{

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.optionsfragmentnew, container, false);

        ListView cListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.currencyListView);
        String[] test = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"};
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, test);

        //View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.optionsfragmentnew, container, false);
        cListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        cListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: add the stack trace from the log cat.

Comment: I guess you should get rid of `cListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the adapter during `onActivityCreated()` method and not during `onCreateView()`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code will help You

```
public class OptionsFragment extends Fragment {

ListView list;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    list = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
    String[] test = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"};
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, test);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

}